# Ошибка поочередной отрисовки в MonoGame(MonoGame это расширение для visual studio с помощью которого можно делать игры)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

Я решил сделать 2D игру в жанре: горизонтальный скролл-шутер. Принцип работы очень прост в основном есть 2 поочередно вызываемых метода: Draw(отвечает за отрисовку графики),Update(считывает нажатие клавиш, обрабатывает игровую логику) и еще есть DownloadContent(Который загружает контент(2D texture)).
Я сделал несколько состояний игры:menu(когда игрок в меню),game(когда игрок в игре),gamepause(пауза),
death(когда игрок умирает)-в зависимости от этих состояний на сцене отрисовываются разные игровые объекты. Сделал я это через простейшее условие.

```
 enum Stat
{
    mainMenu,
    GameFon,
}

//а вот условие из за которого поочерёдно выводятся методы


switch (Stat)
            {
                case Stat.mainMenu:
                    mainMenu.Update();
          if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))  Stat = Stat.GameFon; 
                    break;
                case Stat.GameFon:
                    GameFon.Draw(_spriteBatch);
          if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) Stat = Stat.mainMenu;
                    player.Update();
                    break;


            }
```

Теперь ближе к сути, когда при нажатии на пробел(именно на эту клавишу я сделал переход состояния menu на game) должен вызываться метод DrawGame вот он:

```
     public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            
            spriteBatch.Draw(bgLayer2, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1650, 1050), Color.White);
//ошибка возникает здесь при запуске со словами что исключение не сработало
// хотя ошибок нет и ничего не подчеркивается 
            
            
        }
```

Но visual Studio пишет что исключение не сработало и предлагает запустить последний успешно скомпилированный файл хотя все написано верно. Вопрос: что я должен сделать чтобы эти картинки наконец-то начали меняется? Игра уже готова в ней реализовано много механик но из за какой-то ошибки
с исключением оно не хочет работать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: спасибо но в самом проекте у меня причисление  через запятую. Проблема в исключениях

Comment: Нет, проблема у вас не в исключениях. Ваш код банально не компилируется, о чём вам и говорит Студия, предлагая запустить последний скомпилированный вариант. Исправьте синтаксические ошибки!

Comment: в самом проекте у меня совершено другой код, этот я написал для примера

Comment: с логикой отрисовки проблем нет

Comment: ок я сейчас исправлю свой вопрос, спасибо. Я просто впервые их задаю на stack flow , прошу не сердится.